# Cursor disappears in office 2010 applications NOT while typing

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, windows-8.1, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

We have a problem with multiple HP Elite pads running Windows 8.1 and Office 2010 where if an Office application (mainly Word and Outlook seen so far) is running and the device is put into the docking station, the mouse cursor disappears when it enters any of the Office applications but reappears over any other application. The only way we have been able to get the cursor back is with Ctrl-Alt-Del or restarting the application. This has nothing to do with cursor hiding while typing setting, that was the first thing I checked.

After spending an hour Google searching, the closest thing I could find was a similar unanswered question [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6099b31b-5f65-47d7-b7a3-ac60eec55971/disappearing-cursor-in-word-2010)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.